# Simplifying a =Mid() formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I want to test if the first letter in cell A1 is an "A".

> =Mid(A1, 1, 1)="A"

Now let's say I want to find out if either the first or fourth letter in cell A1 is an "A".

I would have thought you could something like this:

> =Mid(A1, or(1,4), 1)="A"

Instead of having to do this:

> =IF(MID(A1,1,1)="A",TRUE,IF(MID(A!,4,1)="A",TRUE,FALSE))

Am I on the right track?
Can I make the formula simpler?

Comment: Another good way would be to use regex. But that requires adding reference in VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this formula, `=OR(MID(A2,{1,4},1)="A")` but enter as "array formula".  I.e., press ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter as you normally do.

Comment: Works for me. If i want to change output, i simply put if in front and values at end.

Comment: +1 .....but, in general, formulas that use "array constants" like `{1,4}` don't need array entry - so this doesn't require CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. If `{1,4}` was calculated in some way or from cell references then you would, e.g. if Z1 contains 1 and Z2 contains 4 then this version `=OR(MID(A2,Z1:Z2,1)="A")` requires CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to give correct results in all cases

Comment: @barryhoudini, didn't know about array constant thing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use AND function

```
=OR(Mid(A1, 1, 1)="A",Mid(A1, 4, 1)="A")
```

AND recieve logical inputs test, and return an "AND" operation between all of them

then, you just Use it on the IF

**EDIT:**
Considering the comments, you should use the function separator considering your decimal separator.
As you should use commas as decimal separator, you will need semi colons to separate function's arguments. In this case, assuming you use period to separate decimal numbers, you will use commas to separate function's arguments.
Thanks for the comments.
(sorry for the bad English)

Comment: Shouldn't your semi-colon be a comma?

Comment: AND recieves logical values separated by a semi-colon. Considering MID will return a logical value, needs a ";" to later recieve the other MID/logical value

Comment: at least, in my excel 2007 spanish (just opened) needs a semi-colon,not a comma

Comment: @HeadOfCatering in locales that use a comma as the decimal separator, you use semicolons to delimit function arguments.

Comment: you're right.. sorry, use the Spanish Excel. Thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: @ElVieejo in locales that use a period as the decimal separator, you use commas to delimit function arguments.

Comment: @ElVieejo, I think you should simply point out that you need either a comma or semi-colon depend on locale.

Comment: Shouldn't be OR() function instead of AND()?

Comment: you're right, My english is very bad, I understand that he wants both letters as an "A"

Answer (score 1):

The OR function needs to be on the outside:

```
=OR(MID(A1, 1, 1)=”A”, MID(A1, 4, 1)=”A”)
```